# How to overwrite Google analytics metrics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

We have a data layer variable coming from javascript on page load, which then is used as custom metrics in tag, which is populating analytics report. Now it is increasing metrics value each time user is refreshing the page, but we need to overwrite its value instead. I tried to find corresponding setting in tag/variable configuration, but failed. Tag type is universal analytics. Would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Custom metrics automatically get summed up at reporting time, so that is why you see it incrementing. Have you considered changing it to a custom dimension instead, depending on what you are capturing and whether it makes better sense or not?

Comment: It works in pair with custom dimension, basically it resembles an order number-product index and price value pair.

Comment: One possibility would be to use another custom dimension for your "metric", scoped at the hit-level, along with the corresponding custom dimension. Although not ideal, it would capture the different values for the price associate with the product. 

Alternatively, depending on your site, you could try using enhanced ecommerce in which you could capture these products and their values.

Comment: Thank you. The best approach here probably is to use enhanced ecommerce or to push this data only once per order.